# Add timeout to complex Task.WhenAll

Tags: c#

I have a Task collector that run async tasks (the commented one) :

```
public Task<ResultOrException<T>[]> WhenAllOrException<T>(IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
{
    return Task.WhenAll(
        tasks.Select(
            task => task.ContinueWith(
                t => t.IsFaulted
                    ? new ResultOrException<T>(t.Exception)
                    : new ResultOrException<T>(t.Result))));       
}

public class ResultOrException<T>
{
    public ResultOrException(T result)
    {
        IsSuccess = true;
        Result = result;
    }

    public ResultOrException(Exception ex)
    {
        IsSuccess = false;
        Exception = ex;
    }

    public bool IsSuccess { get; }
    public T Result { get; }
    public Exception Exception { get; }
}
```

This code wait for all task even if they returns after 2 minutes.
I need to ignore all tasks returns with a timeout of five seconds.

I've tried also to change my code this way but it won't compile:

```
return Task.WhenAny(Task.WhenAll(
    tasks.Select(
            task => task.ContinueWith(
                t => t.IsFaulted
                    ? new ResultOrException<T>(t.Exception)
                    : new ResultOrException<T>(t.Result)))

    ), Task.Delay(2000));
```

Or this:

```
var ts = new TimeSpan(1000);

        return await Task.WaitAll(
            tasks.Select(
                task => task.ContinueWith(
                    t => t.IsFaulted
                        ? new ResultOrException<T>(t.Exception)
                        : new ResultOrException<T>(t.Result))),
            ts);
```

How to achieve this?

Comment: You should use a `Task.WaitAll` in this case.  It's a slightly different use case but the `TimeSpan` can be added as a timeout. You won't need to over engineer the tasks or combine `WhenAny` with `WhenAll` either.

Comment: Are you planning to `await` when you call `WhenAllOrException<T>`?

Comment: Ok i forgot to insert async/await but that isn't the problem here.

Comment: @MichaelPuckettII I like waitAll solution with the TimeSpan but using that change the type result from "ResultOrException" to "Task" and i need a ResultOrException type return.

Comment: @PizzoniAlessio `Task` already has result / exception built in.  I recommend looking at `Task.Exception` and understanding how to properly bubble an exception through a `Task`.  I see what you're doing but IMO only I recommend using the standard way that's already proven and implemented in most systems.  Maybe you're not aware you can do this or maybe you're trying to be more specific, which is fine, but it feels over engineered and probably more complicated than it should be.  Have a look at bubbling exceptions through the `Task` and how to properly handle the `Result` and I ….

Comment: … think you may choose to adopt that solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it won't compile

This is because `Task.Delay` returns a `Task`. There's no value or exception there. So it can't be directly combined with a sequence of `ResultOrException<T>`.

You'll need to decide how to report timeouts to your caller. If you want the `Task<ResultOrException<T>[]>` to fault, then you can do this:

```
public async Task<ResultOrException<T>[]> WhenAllOrException<T>(IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
{
    var resultOrExceptions = Task.WhenAll(
        tasks.Select(task => ...)
    );
    var delayTask = Task.Delay(2000);
    var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(resultOrExceptions, delayTask);
    if (completedTask == delayTask)
        throw new TimeoutException();
    return await resultOrExceptions;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to return an array `ResultOrException<T>`, each one faulted with a timeout, then you can do this:

```
public async Task<ResultOrException<T>[]> WhenAllOrException<T>(IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
{
    var resultOrExceptionTasks = tasks.Select(task => ...)
        .ToArray();
    var resultOrExceptions = Task.WhenAll(resultOrExceptionTasks);
    var delayTask = Task.Delay(2000);
    var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(resultOrExceptions, delayTask);
    if (completedTask == delayTask)
        return Enumerable.Repeat(new ResultOrException<T>(new TimeoutException()), resultOrExceptionTasks.Length).ToArray();
    return await resultOrExceptions;
}
```

Or, if you want to return the results that made it in time, and only return timeout exceptions for those that didn't, then you want to move the `WhenAny` *inside* the `WhenAll`:

```
public Task<ResultOrException<T>[]> WhenAllOrException<T>(IEnumerable<Task<T>> tasks)
{
    var delayTask = Task.Delay(2000);
    return Task.WhenAll(tasks.Select(WithTimeout));

    async Task<ResultOrException<T>> WithTimeout(Task<T> task)
    {
        var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, delayTask);
        if (completedTask == delayTask)
            return new ResultOrException<T>(new TimeoutException());
        try
        {
            return new ResultOrException<T>(await task);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new ResultOrException<T>(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Side note: you should [**always** pass a `TaskScheduler` to `ContinueWith`](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/continuewith-is-dangerous-too.html). Also, I have a [`Try` implementation](https://github.com/StephenCleary/Try) that may be useful.